# Whats the point in conserving electricity if the AC current produced cannot be stored?

Tags: power-supply, current, dc, ac

If we cannot save the ac current produced in a battery or some device like the DC current there is no point in conserving it because current once produced should be consumed somehow!!
My faculty said storing AC current is a tough task

Comment: Tough but not impossible.  There is [pumped hydro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity) storage.  However building pumped hydro is a large investment.

Comment: Information only: Battery storage in various forms is becoming economical for gridscale energy storage. Conversion from DC to AC can be accomplished at in excess of 98% efficiency and AC to DC probably about the same.

Answer (score 8):

If it is not consumed it does not need to be produced, which saves on whatever is consumed to produce it. This of course works only if the production level can be changed rapidly, hence the electricity producing companies like to have a mix of cheaper but slowly adapting sources, and more expensive but faster adapting sources.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is that if energy is conserved, then fewer new plants will need to built to supply the demand. This will reduce [capex](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/capitalexpenditure.asp) (which is real money, however it is amortized), reduce pollution, and reduce the need for fossil fuels which have bad side effects from their extraction and their burning (a certain percentage has to be fossil fuels because they are more flexible). As I understand it, you generally want to run hydroelectric plants and nuclear plants flat-out since there is little advantage in running at less power, so they're good for supplying base demand. Thermal plants on the other hand, can be quickly (hours or minutes) started up and shut down and are good for dealing with variations in demand. They consume natural gas or coal more-or-less in proportion to the power demand. As an aside, there was a large thermal plant about 1 mile from me and if the load was shed due to breakers opening (a blackout) that lasted for more than a second or two it seems they would vent the steam to keep the (suddenly unloaded) turbines from spooling up to dangerous RPMs- very noisy.

It is true that if you have a hydroelectric power plant which is capable of supplying, say, 1GW and the consumption drops from 800MW to 750MW there is little measurable saving.

An analogy might be the need for a new roads- if everyone worked from home one (random) day a work week then the need for new lanes on a highway might be put off for many years, pollution would be reduced and energy saved. It might even save money if the people were as productive at home as at the office.

One might argue that it would be better to mass produce plenty enough nuclear plants (or fusion plants if you want to go all sci-fi) so that excess energy could just be dumped or stored (for example, by pumping water up Niagara falls from Lake Ontario to Lake Erie while the plants adjust to the load. Energy too cheap to meter- one promise of the early atomic age. Some of these arguments are more public policy and political in nature, so this is no place for them.

Comment: I wouldn't agree on the working regimes for the plant types. Hydro is very often used for finetuning supply and demand. They just change the waterflow which is proportional to power. Hydro is often used for the so called "black start" of the power system. This represents the booting of the power system after a total blackout in a very large area. Natural gas is on par or faster in this role. Regarding nuclear I would say that you reduce the consumption of fissile material by inserting the control rods partially into the core.

Comment: @Kurtovic Fair enough- my point was that the cost of running a hydro or nuke plant is almost fixed whether it runs flat out or produced very little power, so it's obviously better to maximize the output to minimize cost per kWh.

Comment: I agree with you :-). The role of load matching shouldn't be underestimated. Plants are getting paid to be ready to supply power for demand peaks. If you bring in the reactive power demands of the system you get one more layer which complicates everything, and which hasn't been satisfactionary been solved for open electricity markets. I'm sorry for the nitpicking :-). I guess you didn't want to go so deep into it with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Power companies are in the business of making money so if everyone used 10% less electricity long term they would adjust their output to maximize profits.  This in turn would mean us using less natural resources, creating less pollution and waste.

So while turning off your lights one day might not do anything making a habit of reducing your consumption would have an effect.   You could argue that if only you do it that might not make a difference, but if enough people do it will.

The other obvious benefit, is using less will cost you less.  Except when power companies try to adjust for less consumption by trying to get a rate increase approved or charging people who use solar for the privilege of connecting to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Most electricity is produced by means of a steam-turbine generator which has a rather massive flywheel. If current is allowed to flow in the generator's coils, it current will generate torque in a direction to oppose the generator's rotation, thus taking kinetic energy from the flywheel. The more kinetic energy is taken from the flywheel, the more steam energy will need to be used to keep it spinning at the proper speed.  The more steam energy is used for that purpose, the more heat will need to be produced to replace it.  The more heat is required, the more fuel fill be fed into the generator (or, for nuclear generators, the faster the nuclear reactions will be allowed to proceed).